# Delete request fails with 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, mobx

I am working on a React application that uses MobX, and have encountered a problem with implementing the Delete HTTP request. All the other requests work fine.

MobX store action:

```
        try {
            await agent.Artworks.delete(id);
                this.artworkRegistry.delete(id);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

Agent methods:
`` del: (url: string) => axios.delete(url).then(responseBody)
delete: (id: string) => requests.del(`/artworks/${id}`) ``

Command handler:

```
{
    public class Delete
    {
        public class Command : IRequest
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
        }
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _context;
            public Handler(DataContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var artwork = await _context.Artworks.FindAsync(request.Id);
                if (artwork == null) 
                    throw new Exception("Could not find artwork");
                _context.Remove(artwork);    
                var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;  
                if (success) return Unit.Value;
                throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console gives me the following error:
`Object { data: {…}, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }`

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the request look like?

Comment: @TimothyG. from the console log error: https://imgur.com/pWW4UgC

Answer (score 1):

The request that you are sending is malformed. You are getting a `415` response error which is: **415 Unsupported Media Type**

That means that server is refusing to process the request because it doesn't recognize the format the request is in. So there is also a possibility that your server is misconfigured. Try sending the request outside your app (via terminal using `curl`) and see what kind of response you get.

You can read more on [MDN 415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)

Comment: Sending the request in Postman gives me the following `{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "A non-empty request body is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|e4802168-4f3ad7454739c02f."
}`

Comment: Well, there you go  `body` of the request can't be empty. The server is obviously expecting something to be in the body of the request.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1
states 
```
The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
   will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
   a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
   message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```